# Echo Custom response message , contact form 7 before send email hook

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to show a custom message below or above contactform7, without sending the email. I tired it using before_send_email function, but nothing is working. below is the function I have used.

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else");  
    function wpcf7_do_something_else($cf7) {
        $wpcf->skip_mail = true;
        // Here I tried to use jquery or wordpress filter function to display custom message. but nothing is displaying.
        return $wpcf;
    }
```

Please help

Comment: $wpcf7->skip_mail = true doesn't do anything, because you haven't defined that object in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to return a custom message on the form submission, you can use the filter `wpcf7_ajax_json_echo`

try that :

```
add_filter("wpcf7_ajax_json_echo", function ($response, $result) {


    $response["message"] = "a custom message";


    return $response;

});
```

Comment: You should add `10, 2` when registering your filter. Otherwise the second param `$result` will never get passed to your filter and it will cause notices.

Comment: alternatively, just omit $result (unused).

Comment: This is deprecated for 'wpcf7_feedback_response'