# Contact Form 7: How to replace the form with an HTML code after submission?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am developing a web form with `WordPress` and `Contact Form 7`. The form is working OK. However, I want the entire form to be replaced with a thank you message and an image. I don't want to redirect to a thank you page. I want to just replace the form and stay on the same page. Can you understand?

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46939659/2343086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DOM Events as stated on this [Contact Form 7 Documentation Page](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

For your example the code could look like this:

script.js

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
  let form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  let thankYouMessage = document.getElementById("thankYou");

  form.style.display = 'none';
  thankYouMessage.style.display = 'block';

}, false );
```

your HTML file:

```
<form id="myForm">
</form>

<div id="thankYou">
<img src="" />
<h2>Thank you for your submit!</h2>

</div>
```

Now just set `display:none;` for the container with id `thankYou` and you are good to go!

Comment: It's almost correct! `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. Then the result must be indexed. ;-) But... Thank You!

Comment: @JosédeFrança You are absolutely right! You are welcome. :-)